# gradle sync failed with 1 warning Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin to 16.0.4

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio-3.0

i tried all possible methods and it still did not sync please help. Below is my whole gradle file, i have tried to merge the firebase core and messaging but it still shows the error

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.1.1'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.arturogutierrez:badges:1.0.5@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.broakenmedia:CharCountTextView:v1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.broakenmedia:MultiContactPicker:1.8.3'
    implementation 'com.github.lguipeng:BubbleView:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.rockerhieu.emojicon:library:1.3.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'

}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Below is the error message

Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 16.0.4.

Comment: Add error message please.

Comment: i have added the error message below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **project** build.gradle file, replace with below line:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'//the latest version is 4.2.0

    }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome, could you accept or upvote my answer thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using different versions of firebase dependencies. That may be the reason for the failure. Update the google-services to latest version and use same version for firebase dependencies..

```
// as you can see different versions for firebase dependecies
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
```

Either use 16.0.4 or the latest version of firebase dependencies.